# How can I sync availability across multiple Google calendars?

Tags: google-calendar-api, zapier

I'm a part of multiple organizations that all use Google Calendar (and I use it for my personal calendar as well).

I need a setup so that when I'm booked on one calendar, it makes me unavailable on all calendars. I've tried setting up a Zapier that adds an event to my personal calendar if an event is booked on my work calendar, and vice versa. This resulted in an endless loop where I had auto-events creating auto-events creating auto-events.

Simply put, I'd like to have a way where I can give someone a calendly link (or something similar) that takes into account my availability across my multiple calendars.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your original approach will work, you just need a way to filter out automatically created events. I'd suggest putting a prefix in the event name and then filtering on that. For example "Auto-Event - Busy". Then each of the two zaps (work -> personal and vice versa) filter to only create the matching event if the created event doesn't have a title like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up automatic two-way sync of Google calendar events between multiple organizations using SyncPenguin. Please check out [this article](https://syncpenguin.com/syncs/google-calendar-events-sync/) for more details.

It describes a platform built for two-way and one-way sync, so you should not have any problems with looping.`